# Recommended Survey system

Tags: open-source, software-development, web-development, survey

Which is the best open-source system or framework for a survey that aims to collect data from users?
because I don't wanna build a survey system from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SurveyMonkey](https://surveymonkey.com). At certain point, is free and no installation needed.

Comment: it's not free and not even open source!

Comment: Limesurvey is open-source. The project was no activity since 2017. But, is an open-source option: [limesurvey on sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/limesurvey)

Comment: Limesurvey is now here https://www.limesurvey.org/ but free version may be limited...